# Special rename with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to make some URL changes using `.htaccess`.
I need to rewrite or redirect from this:

```
example.com/masonry_gallery/project1
```

To this:

```
example.com/project1-detalle
```

In other words, that is to remove the `/masonry_gallery/` part, and adding "-detalle" at the end of the URL.

I have tried several combinations without any luck. I appreciate if someone could give me a hand.

**UPDATE:** This is how the htaccess file looks like now:

```
RewriteRule ^masonry_gallery/(project1)$ /$1-detalle [R,L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example it's a one-to-one *redirect*. Try the in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/masonry_gallery/(project1)$ /$1-detalle
```

This assumes you are not already using mod_rewrite for other rewrites/redirects.

**UPDATE:** Since you are using WordPress (which uses mod_rewrite) try the following instead *at the top* of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^masonry_gallery/(project1)$ /$1-detalle [R,L]
```

Change this to a 301 only when you are sure it is working OK (if this is intended to be a permanent redirect). ie. Change `R` to `R=301`.

> there will be some other projects in the future, so the URL will probably change on the part it says "project1", to include project2, project3, project4, etc... Could you please consider this to include something like (*) or the required value in order for it to work with **any number**?

By "number" I assume any number of digits 0-9 (but at least 1 digit), then try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^masonry_gallery/(\d+)$ /$1-detalle [R,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your suggestion but it is not working yet. Probably because we do have other conditions in our htaccess, as you mention at the end. Here is the current htaccess file:

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RedirectMatch 302 ^(/masonry_gallery/project1)$ $1-detalle


# END WordPress

Comment: Not sure if I did it well, but still not working. It seems it is doing some redirections but the result is taking me to the home page. This is how the htaccess file looks like now: 


RewriteRule ^masonry_gallery/(project1)$ /$1-detalle [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: - - - -  Another thing to mention, there will be some other projects in the future, so the url will probably change on the part it says "project1", to include project2, project3, project4, etc...   Could you please consider this to include something like (*) or the required value in order for it to work with any number? Than you again for your help.

Comment: "doing some redirections"? What do you mean? More than one redirection? Check the network traffic in the browser - what do you see? Does it work if you request `/project1-detalle` directly? I've updated my answer to work with "any number". (But if the earlier directive didn't work, then this is unlikely to work as well.)

Comment: Tks.. applied, but I don't know if you received my previous message? maybe you only read the last one? Here it is again: 

Not sure if I did it well, but still not working. It seems it is doing some redirections but the result is taking me to the home page. This is how the htaccess file looks like now: RewriteRule ^masonry_gallery/(project1)$ /$1-detalle [R,L] # BEGIN WordPress <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule . /index.php [L] </IfModule> # END WordPress –

Comment: Yes, I saw that - looks OK. Please answer the queries in my last comment.

Comment: Tks. Well, what I mean with "doing some redirections", is only that the page is definitely not loading the original link, but going somewhere else. It is supposed to go to the url "example.com/project1-detalle" but instead is going to the home page. 

Yes, if I go to example.com/project1-detalle directly it does open up the page correctly.

Comment: Make sure the browser cache is cleared. That directive should redirect `/masonry_gallery/project1` to `/project1-detalle`. The same as requesting `/project1-detalle` directly. So, if it's not doing that then it would seem the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (ie. `^masonry_gallery/(project1)$`) is not matching the requested URL?

Comment: Ok, I cleared the cache, and even tried with another browser but the same. It goes to the home page. What do you mean by "not matching the requested url?"

Comment: That `RewriteRule` _pattern_ should match `/masonry_gallery/project1`, which is the URL you are presumably requesting?

Comment: Hmmm strange. Is `/masonry_gallery` a physical directory? If so, is there an `.htaccess` file in this subdirectory that contains mod_rewrite directives?? (That URL you posted appears to contain a trailing slash - this will not match the above directive. However, even removing the trailing slash the outcome is the same. So this suggests _something else_ is going on here.)

Comment: No, masonry_gallery is apparently a friendly name one of the plugins create. Not a physical directory.

Comment: There is certainly _something else_ going on here. Requesting `/masonry_gallery/<anything>` redirects to the home page?! "Yes, if I go to `example.com/project1-detalle` directly it does open up the page correctly" - although that would seem to be a 404?

Comment: Weird.. /masonry_gallery/<anything> does redirects to the home page.
And example.com/project1-detalle opens correctly because it is a real wordpress page. I also tried using this: RedirectMatch 301 /masonry_gallery(.*) /$1 ... it makes the redirect but adds a "/" before the -detalle part. Maybe there is a way to remove that "/"?
original: 
example.com/masonry_gallery/project1
what I get: 
example.com/project1/-detalle

Comment: If `RedirectMatch` "worked" then try the directive I posted in my answer. However, this is a bit odd. `RedirectMatch` is a mod_alias directive (as opposed to mod_rewrite, which is what all the other directives are), so executes independently. If it works then go with it, but this is not recommended - there would seem to be something else going on here. Temporarily... just try removing this `.htaccess` file, does your site still work?

Comment: Hi. No, if I remove the .htaccess file the site goes down. What do you recommend, or what would be the command line if using RedirectMatch?

Comment: It seems to be redirecting OK now (although it results in a 404)?

Comment: Problem solved!. The line was missing a "/" at the end for it to work, and it was not possible editing the htaccess file directly. It was done using a plugin. For some reason WordPress manages it differently. Thank you for your help.